# Pass result of programmtical Android permission request to cordova "callbackContext"?

Tags: android, cordova, permissions, request

I use

```
private void requestPermission(CallbackContext callbackContext) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this.cordova.getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_PERMISSION_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
}
```

to request a permission in my cordova plugin. The question now is for me, how do I pass the result into my `callbackContext` if the only way to get the result is via

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
...}
```

which has no way of getting the callbackContext of requestPermissions() anymore?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Bye

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not pass the callback context to a callback method like this you have to assign the callback context to an instance variable so it is accessible in the method.

```
private CallbackContext callbackContext; // declare the instance variable
```

And as soon you know what the callback context (it is passed to the `execute` method) you assign it to the variable:

```
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
  this.callbackContext = callbackContext;
}
```

And later in your callback method you can use it like that:

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
  this.callbackContext.success(); 
}
```